# Simplifying SumIFs formulas for efficient excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

The overall question is how to calculate The total amount of sales of a Cleaning business in NY and NJ over a calendar year.

I am trying to simplify a formula where you are using sumifs using the same two criteria the whole time, but summing across a range of 12 columns.  I have successfully calculated what I need to by repeating the sumifs portion 24 times for each month and each criteria.  There's got to be an easier way that I'm missing.

```
=SUMIFS($D$2:$D$28,$C$2:$C$28,"NY",$B$2:$B$28,"Cleaning")+SUMIFS($D$2:$D$28,$C$2:$C$28,"NJ",$B$2:$B$28,"Cleaning")+SUMIFS($E$2:$E$28,$C$2:$C$28,"NY",$B$2:$B$28,"Cleaning")+SUMIFS($E$2:$E$28,$C$2:$C$28,"NJ",$B$2:$B$28,"Cleaning")+SUMIFS($F$2:$F$28,$C$2:$C$28,"NY",$B$2:$B$28,"Cleaning")+SUMIFS($F$2:$F$28,$C$2:$C$28,"NJ",$B$2:$B$28,"Cleaning")    and so on and so forth.........
```

[image: Screen shot of table]

I have tried researching sumproduct, index matches, and different arrays to use, but I have not had any luck applying what I have read here or on Youtube to a type of problem like this, and I'm pretty stuck.

Comment: Well, first idea is to do "N*" and that should halve the number...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FILTER` to filter the array of sales by the business and state. Note the `*` and `+` operators in the `FILTER` formula represent logical `AND` and `OR`.

Use `SUM` to sum up all the values in the filtered array.

```
=SUM(FILTER($C$1:$F$9,($A$1:$A$9="Cleaning")*(($B$1:$B$9="NY")+($B$1:$B$9="NJ"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Would "N*" still work? works with sumif() as I was just testing it.

Comment: @SolarMike yes with just this sample data, but I'm considering it's just sample data and he might have other N* states in his full data, or other non-N* states that he wants to include in the sum. But you're right, N* works with this data set and is simpler.

Comment: @kevin you're right - there are a total of 8 states with N as the first letter...

Comment: Yup, Problem I shared I just generated quickly to help solve a much bigger set of data unrelated to what I posted haha!  @SolarMike, that's awesome to think of the wildcard too for that data set.  Thank you both!!

Comment: @pando44 if it comes in handy then that's good. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could declare the condition(s) using LET and use MMULT, so you do not need to repeat `$B$1:$B$9=...`:

```
=LET(c,{"NY","NJ"},
SUM(C2:F9*MMULT((B2:B9=c)*(A2:A9="Cleaning"),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(c))^0)))
```